# Using XForms to select and run an Xquery in eXistDB

Tags: xquery, xforms, exist-db

I'm looking into Xforms and eXistDB and I'm stuck on wether it is possible to have say a selection dropdown and use the selection as a variable and run a xquery in eXist that returns the results. 
I know that this can be easily done with a html-form like `<form method="GET" action="xquery-to-call.xq">` but I'd like to use the advanced features of XForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [XSLTForms Files](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/apps/public-repo/packages/xsltforms.html) and [XSLTForms Demo](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/apps/public-repo/packages/xsltforms-demo.html) apps in the eXist-db public repository. You can find and install these into your local eXist instance via Dashboard > Package Manager. (I recommend XSLTForms over betterForms, since the latter is no longer maintained.) Once both the Files and Demo apps are installed, open http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/XSLTForms-Demo/index.html, and you'll be able to browse the examples and explore the source code.

For more database-driven examples, see the XRX Wikibook at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XRX.